# How can I get folders in a document library to "group" for my custom view? Folders sit in a blank / ungrouped category

Tags: view, sorting, sharepoint-library

I have a simple document library with a custom view that uses the group feature. My coworker setup a list that manages to group folders, but I cannot replicate the effort. Please see the images to see what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7qg5.jpg

Second image shows folder in a "blank" / unlabeled group. First image is what I am trying to achieve. But when I edit the details for a folder, it doesn't let me pick a column.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the views and there is option as show in folder. select that and you will achieve what you want